# Javascript function with multiple if statements not working

Tags: javascript, html, function, if-statement

All of my if statements work on their own, but when I have all of them inside the function, I cannot get all of them to work.

```
function validate()
{
    var x = document.forms["myForm"]["patientName"].value;
    var y = document.forms["myForm"]["patientId"].value;
    var z = document.forms["myForm"]["patientEmail"].value;
    var yL = y.toString().length;
    var search1 = z.search("@");
    var search2 = z.search(".");
    if (myForm.emailReceipt.checked == true) {
    if (x == "" || y == "" || Z == ""){
            alert("Name, ID, and Email must be filled out");
        }else if (search1 == -1 || search2 == -1){
            alert("Please submit a valid email address");
        }
    if ((myForm.emailReceipt.checked == false) && (x == "" || y == "" )) {
        alert("Name and ID must be filled out");
    }
    if (yL !== 8){
        alert("ID must be 8 digits long");
    }
}
```

Comment: `Z == ""` should be `z == ""`  (lowercase).

Comment: It's not clear if `if (myForm.emailReceipt.checked == true) {` should return immediately or not because it's unclosed. If that condition should close over all the other conditions then `if ((myForm.emailReceipt.checked == false) &&....` will never work.

Comment: I also think that this validator unnecessarily validates too many things at once. Because of that, you run into having the test for `x`, `y`, of `z` being empty, followed by a test for `x` or `y` being empty a bit later, which is redundant. You should split the validator into three field-specific ones and then write a validator that composes them.

Answer (score 0):

You should write your code in a clean, formatted way, or use an IDE that does it for you. If you did this, you would realize you have syntax errors because of missing curly braces.

Also, change the uppercase Z to lowercase z in the 2nd condition.

Lastly, be sure to check your conditional logic. For instance, your outer if condition checks if `myForm.emailReceipt.checked == true`, but a condition inside of that checks if `myForm.emailReceipt.checked == false`, which will never pass. This is probably why the conditions work individually but not together. Walk through your logic step by step and add only what's necessary.

Here is an error-free version of your code, but still requires you to walk through your logic and fix accordingly:

```
function validate() {
    var x = document.forms["myForm"]["patientName"].value;
    var y = document.forms["myForm"]["patientId"].value;
    var z = document.forms["myForm"]["patientEmail"].value;
    var yL = y.toString().length;
    var search1 = z.search("@");
    var search2 = z.search(".");

    if (myForm.emailReceipt.checked == true) {
        if (x == "" || y == "" || z == "") {
            alert("Name, ID, and Email must be filled out");
        } else if (search1 == -1 || search2 == -1) {
            alert("Please submit a valid email address");
        }

        if ((myForm.emailReceipt.checked == false) && (x == "" || y == "")) {
            alert("Name and ID must be filled out");
        }

        if (yL !== 8) {
            alert("ID must be 8 digits long");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, your answer contains the original error, although the formatting is much nicer.

Comment: Also `Z` should be `z`

Comment: `Z` changed to `z`. That with thew missing curly brace should resolve all errors.

Comment: In this answer `if ((myForm.emailReceipt.checked == false)` will never hold true because the enclosing condition says it must be `true`.

Comment: @hayavuk You are right, but that is his improper logic and has nothing to do with the ability to execute the function without it throwing an error.

Comment: That doesn't answer the 'question', though. :)

Comment: Truth be told, it's not much of a question to begin with, so this may as well be a 'good' answer.

Comment: I am updating with the information you provided so the answer is as complete as possible.